# How can I add authenticated REST requests for my Node.js App which uses Passport JS based social login?

Tags: node.js, rest, passport.js

I have creating a website running on Node.js and Express. For logging into my website I use passport.js based social login with Google, Facebook and Live.

I need to expose user data via authenticated REST services so that website's Chrome & Firefox browser extension can do CRUD operations.

When user clicks on a button injected via browser extension, I need to check if user is already logged in to website. If user is not logged in then I will do a redirect for login and return back to original page.

I am clueless after this. Which token do I use for REST API calls ?

Any Advice ?

Comment: You should check the [stateless constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) of REST. There is no server side session by REST. This case is interesting, since the authentication is probably up to google or facebook, but I am not certain about what passport.js does. So it may violate the stateless constraint...

Answer (score 0):

After the social login, when the user is redirected to the callback url, you can create your own token, e.g. using uuid, and then send it to the client.

For all the consequent requests the client **needs** to use that token for authentication and you have to manage its expiration.